# Type Of Decision Tree Algorithm by sklearn

Tags: scikit-learn

There are different types of Decision Tree Algorithms. ID3, CART, C4.5.

I needed help to identify which algorithm is implemented by sklearn DecisionTreeClassifier, in Python?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[1.10.6. Tree algorithms: ID3, C4.5, C5.0 and CART](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/tree.html#tree-algorithms-id3-c4-5-c5-0-and-cart):

`CART` (`Classification and Regression Trees`) is very similar to `C4.5`, but it differs in that it supports numerical target variables (regression) and does not compute rule sets. CART constructs binary trees using the feature and threshold that yield the largest information gain at each node.

scikit-learn uses an optimised version of the **CART algorithm**.